# WebCLient ShareCookies between clients. C#

Tags: c#, .net, exception, webclient

Helo.
I want to have few instances of webclient that all share all the cookies. That is because I want to download many items at the same time and I need to be logged in all the time.

This is my WebClientEx Class:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace Rapideo_Client
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A custom WebClient featuring a cookie container
    /// </summary>

    class WebClientEx : WebClient
    {
        public static CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

        public WebClientEx()
        {
            CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        }

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
            if (request is HttpWebRequest)
            {
                (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
            }
            return request;
        }
    }
}
```

This is part of code where I'm getting exception:

```
        using (WebClientEx tempWebClient = new WebClientEx())
        {
            siteTemp = tempWebClient.DownloadString("http://rapideo.pl/lista");
        }
```

And this exception that I'm getting in this code:

```
    System.Net.WebException was unhandled by user code
  Message=An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
       at Rapideo_Client.Rapideo.ReadTransferMB() in e:\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Rapideo Client\Rapideo Client\Rapideo.cs:line 78
       at Rapideo_Client.Rapideo.Refresh() in e:\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Rapideo Client\Rapideo Client\Rapideo.cs:line 50
       at Rapideo_Client.MainWindow.RefreshTimer_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Rapideo Client\Rapideo Client\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 74
       at System.Timers.Timer.MyTimerCallback(Object state)
  InnerException: System.IO.IOException
       Message=Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
            at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsState.RetrieveBytes(Int32& bytesRetrieved)
            at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream, CompletionDelegate completionDelegate, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
            at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
       InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
            Message=An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
            Source=System
            ErrorCode=10054
            NativeErrorCode=10054
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
                 at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
            InnerException:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added public method to my WebCliet that copies Cookies from argument to internal collection